# SELECT rows without duplicates and WHERE IN ()

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
   SELECT formid, avals(data) as datavalues, akeys(data) as datakeys, taskid
      FROM task_form_data
      WHERE taskid IN (449750,449699,449620) 
      ORDER BY formid, timestamp DESC
```

Would be a test query -Problem is  that the table (which i cant change) has newer rows added with new data - but formid remains same.

So when i select like that i get old data aswell.
I cannot use DISTINCT ON (formid). I would need the newest  results ( often 3-4 rows with diff formid) - for each of the taskid IN (comes from php - can be large number  - cant do separate query for each).
IS there any way to get it working like that?

Data example(just a quick example - larger date value would be oldest timestamp):

```
formid  timestamp  taskid
6       1          449750
2       2          449750  
2       3          449750
4       4          449750
4       5          449750
```

What should come out(number of various formid-s can be larger or smaller):

```
6       1          449750
2       2          449750  
4       4          449750
```

UPDATE:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(formid) formid, avals(data) as datavalues, akeys(data) as datakeys, taskid, timestamp
      FROM task_form_data
      WHERE taskid IN (450567,449699,449620)
      GROUP BY formid,taskid,data,timestamp
      ORDER BY formid,timestamp DESC
```

I tried that - it seems to work - but only with the first parameter in where taskid IN.
Could it be modified to work with each value in the array?

Comment: keep track of the last time you ran the query, then have `where ... and timestamp > $time_of_last_query`?

Comment: Late reply - didn't have internet access for a bit.

Problem is that there is data for various persoons (unique id) - the formid can be reused - but data is different.

Comment: can't you create one identity column or create-date column on this table ?Because there should be some column to identity newest row.
Row_number() over(partition by formid,taskid order by NewIdentityColumn desc)

Comment: it has unique id and timestamp is the create date.

But selecting ALL the newest formid-s for each taskid is the issue.
Distinct would end up with just one instance of each formid - not per group (separate for each taskid).

row numberer example  is fixed - but there may be 2 or 10 forms etc for each taskid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()`.  For instance, if you want the three most recent rows:

```
SELECT formid, avals(data) as datavalues, akeys(data) as datakeys, taskid
FROM (SELECT d.*, row_number() over (partition by formid, taskid order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      FROM task_form_data d
      WHERE taskid IN (449750, 449699, 449620)
     ) d
WHERE seqnum <= 3
ORDER BY taskid, formid, timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: that one again would likely provide wrong results.

Each taskid might have any number of formid-s with own data.
Some may be  old data - others updated/added later.

Doing that would simply choose top 3 latest in the table(regardless of if its a duplicate or not) - but what i would need is the newest row for each formid per taskid.

Comment: @MauroTamm You mean the timestamp can be duplicated? It is not possible to distinguish _newest_ row.

Comment: They will not be the same - each row still has unique timestamp, even if its milliseconds.
But i need newest one for each group. IF the id is for example 4567 - it would return 8 rows.
formid-s would be  12,14,12,14,15,23,12,14  each wit ha timestamp. I would need only the newest ones (12,14,15,23) - BUT  its not jus ta single parameter (taskid) but an array  - so it would need to do that for each taskid in the array.

Comment: @MauroTamm . . . That just requires putting `formid` in the `partition by` clause (along with `taskid`).

Comment: Had to lower seq number evaluation to 1 and tat seemed to give the right results. Need to test the data first tho and see if its correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like this, but if your table is not huge it can work:

```
SELECT tfm.formid, tfm.avals(data) as datavalues, tfm.akeys(data) as datakeys, tfm.taskid
FROM task_form_data AS tfm
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT formid, MAX(timestamp)
    FROM task_form_data
    WHERE taskid IN (449750,449699,449620)
    GROUP BY formid
) AS a
ON tfm.formid = a.formid
AND tfm.timestamp = a.timestamptimestamp
WHERE tfm.taskid IN (449750,449699,449620) 
ORDER BY tfm.formid, timestamp DESC;
```

Did you really called a field "timestamp"?

Comment: i didn't call it. as i said, i cannot change the database - i have to work with existing one.

Comment: And this:
ERROR:  column "formid" does not exist
LINE 5:     SELECT formid, MAX(timestamp)

Comment: There was a missing line, sorry:
FROM task_form_data

Comment: ;) 
There is an entry for table "tfm", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: I admint, I didn't recreate the entire table. In this case the "tfm." in the subquery is wrong. Editing.

Comment: yeah but tat rises more problems :D
column a.timestamptimestamp does not exist
which i assumed was a typo - but its the saame with a.timestamp

adding timestamp to the select and group by in subquery ends with: schema "tfm" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

This matches you desired output. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cada8/2)

```
select *
from (
    select *,
        row_number() over(partition by taskid order by timestamp) as rn
    from (
        select distinct on (taskid, formid) *
        from task_form_data
        where taskid in (449750,449699,449620)
        order by taskid, formid, timestamp
    ) s
) s
where rn <= 3
order by taskid, timestamp
```

With the real timestamp it is necessary to add `desc` everywhere it is used to order because a newer timestamp is bigger than an older one.

Comment: It would work - if i knew for sure that there would be only max 3.